# Protractor C# AngularJS only works if IgnoreSynchronization = true

Tags: c#, angularjs, protractor

I'm new to Protractor, and testing an AngularJS application. My test code only works if I set IgnoreSynchronization = true. If IgnoreSynchronization = false, I get the following error:

> The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:7055/hub/session/3f4d701c-f10d-406e-9c34-4648c392e897/execute_async timed out after 60 seconds.

This occurs on a simple code segment like this:

```
        try
        {
            var logo = ngDriver.FindElement(By.Id("headerLogo"));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

I tried setting SetScriptTimeout to a (much) higher value but that didn't help. It simply makes the code wait longer and then a similar timeout error occurs after the waiting period is over.

I've read these threads: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/973 and https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md, and from my newbie interpretation, they seem to indicate that the timeout is caused by the application constantly polling in the background (something to do with $timeOut)?.

Is there anything I can do in my Protractor test code to fix this issue or do I need to go back to the developers of the application?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like protractor waits for angular to signal it's readiness and it never does.

Comment: Can you help elaborate on what Angular has to do to indicate that it's ready? I just want to have a more specific message to send to the developers. Thanks!

Comment: I would ask devs if they use the `$timeout` service, if yes, ask them to use `$interval` instead, see more at https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/169.